# Other app is making my Android app's BLE scan VERY slow

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

It seems like my app's BLE scan performance has progressively slowed since, I believe, Nougat.  I can go back now and test on Marshmallow and see definitively that the problem does not exist there, but I don't have a device on Nougat anymore.  My Pixel 3a on Pie shows the problem severely.

**THE PROBLEM**

When my app is doing a BLE scan and the device I'm looking for is right in front of me, it usually takes 30 - 60 seconds, sometimes more, before the LE scan returns that device in the ScanCallback.  My scan code is pretty straightforward:

```
private synchronized void startScan(@Nonnull BluetoothAdapter adapter, UUID[] serviceUuids) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        if (serviceUuids != null && serviceUuids.length > 0) {
            adapter.startLeScan(serviceUuids, BleScannerService.this);
        } else {
            adapter.startLeScan(BleScannerService.this);
        }
        broadcastUpdate(ACTION_SCAN_STARTED);
    } else {
        List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        if (serviceUuids != null && serviceUuids.length > 0) {
            for (UUID uuid : serviceUuids) {
                filters.add(new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(uuid))
                        .build());
            }
        }
        BluetoothLeScanner scanner = adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        if (scanner != null) {
            ScanSettings.Builder builder = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                    .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                    .setReportDelay(0);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                builder.setMatchMode(ScanSettings.MATCH_MODE_AGGRESSIVE);
            }
            adapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(filters,
                    builder.build(),
                    mScanCallback);
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_SCAN_STARTED);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

A good chunk of that code is specifying ScanSettings that are already the defaults, but I was at my wit's end trying everything.  So I spent a couple days debugging and finally found a really interesting pattern in logcat.

I put out a log every time a device was found in the ScanCallback.  When my scan first starts, it'll only get a result every second or two.  I've even seen it take 10s in between scan results.  It's during this time that my BLE devices is not being found, presumably because whatever huge scan interval the phone is using is not lining up with the BLE device's broadcast interval.

However, at some point it just opens up and I start getting many results per second and my BLE device gets found right away.  I eventually found these logs (this is on Pie) every time right at the moment the floodgates open:

```
2019-08-16 09:13:17.813 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 88:6B:0F:64:2F:D7
2019-08-16 09:13:28.087 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 88:6B:0F:64:2F:D7
2019-08-16 09:13:30.582 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:23:65:B7:D9:43
2019-08-16 09:13:33.024 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 00:07:80:CF:17:B9
2019-08-16 09:13:33.357 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothGatt: close()
2019-08-16 09:13:33.357 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=7
2019-08-16 09:13:33.363 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
2019-08-16 09:13:33.363 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
2019-08-16 09:13:33.407 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:90:AC:1D:EF:38
2019-08-16 09:13:33.491 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:23:65:B7:D9:43
2019-08-16 09:13:33.524 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned F4:5C:89:90:C6:24
2019-08-16 09:13:33.625 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 46:54:BD:32:A2:EF
2019-08-16 09:13:33.708 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned F4:5C:89:90:C6:24
2019-08-16 09:13:34.374 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothGatt: connect() - device: C5:8B:66:21:90:5B, auto: true
2019-08-16 09:13:34.374 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp()
2019-08-16 09:13:34.374 23338-23338/? D/BluetoothGatt: registerApp() - UUID=35e43611-6c73-47a6-ad0d-9919df01108f
2019-08-16 09:13:34.378 23338-23480/? D/BluetoothGatt: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
2019-08-16 09:13:34.408 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:23:65:B7:D9:43
2019-08-16 09:13:34.424 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned F4:5C:89:90:C6:24
2019-08-16 09:13:34.492 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:90:AC:1D:EF:38
2019-08-16 09:13:34.592 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 6F:23:65:B7:D9:43
2019-08-16 09:13:34.608 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned F4:5C:89:90:C6:24
2019-08-16 09:13:34.658 27109-27109/<my package> E/<my app>: BleScannerService.java:275 onLeScan(): WPW: scanned 46:54:BD:32:A2:EF
```

So the instant that close() is done is when the floodgates open.  There's some other app that's holding a gatt trying to connect to something and while that's occurring my app's scan is very slow (maybe Android automatically turns it into SCAN_MODE_OPPORTUNISTIC or SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER ignoring my SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY?).

The other log always present is the "connect() - device: C5:8B:66:21:90:5B, auto: true".  I got lucky and was able to find C5:8B:66:21:90:5B in my phone's bluetooth settings... it's my Garmin GPS watch!

**THE CAUSE**

It would appear that while my watch is either bluetooth off or out of range, the Garmin Connect app is constantly scanning for it (well, trying to connect with auto flag), and that is what causes my BLE scan to return results VERY slowly.  Once the connect times out, my BLE scan screams... Garmin Connect does another connect during my BLE scan, but I guess now my scan takes seniority and it stays fast until I cancel it and start it again.  Then it's slow until Garmin's connect times out again.

I confirmed this is the problem in a couple ways:

1. I uninstalled Garmin Connect.  My app runs great, scans fast every time.
2. I turn on my watch's bluetooth so the phone is connected to it (thus isn't trying to find it anymore).  My app runs great, scans fast every time.

Going back to a phone on Marshmallow, the above issue doesn't happen at all, even with Garmin Connect installed but the watch not connected.  My assumption is that something changed in Android that makes the connect() from one app interfere with the startScan() in another.  In Marshmallow they didn't interfere with each other, in Pie they do.  I'm guessing it started in Nougat based on a lot of other things I've read, but I can't confirm that.

**IS THERE A SOLUTION?**

I don't know, but I'm hoping someone out there does.  From what I can see, there's really no way to have your app "take over" the bluetooth adapter or try to force itself to have seniority over any other app using it (understandable).

Is there a way to do a BLE scan so that it goes into low latency right away, regardless of what else is going on on the phone?  It certainly worked in Marshmallow...

Comment: Did you figure out how to speed up the scan? I also experience this issue.

Comment: I haven't.  Hoping someone has though!